# InkCanvas : Move strokes

Tags: uwp

When selecting a set of strokes, it should be possible to move them according to the pointer's position.
I have successfully implemented the selection with the help of `StrokeContainer.SelectWithPolyline(IEnumerable<Point>)`, but I don't know how to move them with the `MoveSelected(Point)` function.

**Here's how I proceed:**

On the pointer pressed event, I retrieve the cursor coordinates and update them within the mouse move event after subtracting them from the current pointer's raw position.
When dragging the rectangle, it doesn't work as expected (strokes move on the screen's right edge, so it doesn't even follow the cursor's position).

Sample

```
// Get mouse coordinates
private void UnprocessedInput_PointerPressed(Windows.UI.Input.Inking.InkUnprocessedInput sender, Windows.UI.Core.PointerEventArgs args)
{
    switch (m_CurrentTool)
    {
        case CurrentTool.FreeSelection:
            if (!m_SelectionBoundingRect.Contains(args.CurrentPoint.RawPosition))
            {
                _Selecting = false;
                _HasActiveSelection = false;
                OverlayCanvas.Children.Clear();
            }
            if (!_HasActiveSelection)
            {
                m_LassoSel = new Polyline()
                {
                    StrokeThickness = 2,
                    Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Colors.Magenta),
                    StrokeDashArray = new DoubleCollection() { 4, 6, 1, 4 },
                    Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Color.FromArgb(50, 255, 0, 255))
                };
                m_LassoSel.Points.Add(args.CurrentPoint.RawPosition);
                OverlayCanvas.Children.Add(m_LassoSel);
                _Selecting = true;
                break;
             }
             else
             {
                 _WasMoving = true;
                 Point squareCoords = new Point(0, 0);
                 if (OverlayCanvas.Children.Count > 0)
                 {
                     squareCoords = TransformToVisual(OverlayCanvas.Children[0] as Rectangle).TransformPoint(new Point(0, 0));
                 }
                 // get mouse delta
                 _PreviousMousePosition = new Point(0, 0);
                 _PreviousMousePosition.X = (args.CurrentPoint.Position.X - squareCoords.X);
                 _PreviousMousePosition.Y =  (args.CurrentPoint.Position.Y - squareCoords.Y);
             }
             break;
    }
}

// Move selection according to the cursor's coordinates
private void UnprocessedInput_PointerMoved(Windows.UI.Input.Inking.InkUnprocessedInput sender, Windows.UI.Core.PointerEventArgs args)
{
    if (_WasMoving)
    {
        Point newPosition = new Point(0, 0);
        newPosition.X = (args.CurrentPoint.Position.X - _PreviousMousePosition.X);
        newPosition.Y = (args.CurrentPoint.Position.Y - _PreviousMousePosition.Y);
        _SelectionBoundingRect = RenderTarget_ink.InkPresenter.StrokeContainer.MoveSelected(newPosition);
        _PreviousMousePosition = newPosition;
    }
}
```

Comment: Does my solution work?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to select a stroke, you just need to set the `Selected` property as true.  Then you just need to call the [InkStrokeContainer.MoveSelected](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.input.inking.inkstrokecontainer.moveselected?view=winrt-22621). So it should be something like this:

```
 if (_WasMoving)
        {
            //get select stroke
            var strokes = inkCanvas.InkPresenter.StrokeContainer.GetStrokes();
            // For test purpost, I only have one stroke in the inkcanvas
            InkStroke stroke = strokes.FirstOrDefault();
            stroke.Selected = true;
            // move select stroke to args.CurrentPoint.Position if you put it in the PointerMoved event.
            inkCanvas.InkPresenter.StrokeContainer.MoveSelected(new Point(200,200));
        }
```

I tested the code just in a button click and move the stroke to a hard-coded position. You might need to change the position value based on pointer move event.